# How to achive an extra custom dialog (based on server response) by login in React Admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, authprovider

I want users to be able to choose a **role** as part of the **login process**.
After user gives his `username` and `password`, server sends back the **roles** he have.
How can I achieve a dialog, where user can choose a role from the list of owned roles, before the `login` function of `authProvider` ends?

The `login` function is a regular JavaScript function, not a React function component, so I can not call hooks from it (like `useContext`).

I have two guess:

1. In the `LoginForm` pass an `async` callback function to the `login` method (what is created by `useLogin()`. After server responds in the `login` function with the `roles` of the `user`, call this callback function with `await`.
   In this callback function, I can make the 'Choose a Role' Modal visible. I just don't see, how can I achieve that the program waits until the user hits the `submit` button in the 'Choose a Role' Modal, and only than return a resolved Promise. Is it possible in JS?
2. Create a 'pre-login' form, which accept the `username` and `password`, sends it to the backend, which returns the roles, show the 'Choose a Role' Modal, and call the `authProvider` `login` function only when user submits a role.

I'm really curious about your opinion and thoughts on it.

Comment: Option 2 is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

The `login` function returned by the `useLogin` hook accepts a second argument in addition to the credentials: `redirectTo`. You can provide a custom route which would display either a dedicated page for choosing the role or the login page with a sub route displaying your modal if you really want a modal.

Once the user has chosen its role, you may then redirect to the admin home page by using the `useRedirect` hook.